# I can't see ImageField's photos in DJango's view [Solve]

Tags: python, django

something fail in my Django project, because the images that I load in the imagefields don't show in the view.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fvx6sfmxgm08xo6/AABVR-AQGeF52pCxlzVaLuDaa?dl=0

The crab's photo it's load with "static", but the second, that it's imagefield's photo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TP0u.png)

Model:

```
class foto(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imagen=models.ImageField(upload_to='fotos/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

View:

```
def general(request):
    lista=foto.objects.all()
    context={'material':lista}
    return render(request,'indice.html',context)
```

settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
'/media/fotos/',
    )
```

html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Album de fotos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="{% static 'cangrejo.jpg' %}" />
        {% if material %}
            {% for a in material %}
                <li>{{a.nombre}}: {{a.imagen}}</li>
                <img src="{{a.imagen}}" />
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>No hay fotos</p>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Admin's URLS:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('colecion.urls')),
]
```

View's URLS:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from colecion import views

urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$',views.general),
]
```

Edit: I already solve the problem!

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ciencia/static')
```

models.py

```
foto=models.ImageField()
```

html

```
<img src="{% static alfa.foto %}" />
```

Comment: please put the code in this post so we can see it.

Comment: @NickWeseman In the dropbox's link you can see a full DJango project. This project only have one model and one view.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez you should put the code here nobody would want to open your dropbox link besides that is against the format of this website.

Comment: @SinanUlker I done.

Comment: `o` is a terrible name for a variable

Comment: @MiguelAlparez Have you checked if imagefield's photo was really uploaded the path you are giving  ("/Users/pcx/Documents/album/media/fotos/perro.jpg" )  I mean does this image really exist in the right location?

Comment: @SinanUlker I edit the code. Check the changes.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

[`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-url) - "Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files."

[`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#media-root) - "URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT, used for managing stored files. It must end in a slash if set to a non-empty value. You will need to configure these files to be served in both development and production environments."

Your current config's `MEDIA_URL` doesn't look right. It should be a URL, you have it set to a filesystem path. Try something like

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Change `{{a.imagen}}` to `{{a.imagen.url}}`